# multiple progress bar in javascript

Tags: javascript

hi am trying to show multiple progress bar . below is the code snipnet

```
function Progressbar(id){
   this.id=id;
   this.width=0;
   this.progressInterval=0;
   this.showProgress=function(){
     this.width+=20;
     console.log(this.width);
     console.log(this.id);
     document.getElementById(this.id).style.width=this.width + 'px';
     document.getElementById(this.id).innerHTML=this.width + '%';
     if(this.width==100){
       clearTimeout(this.progressInterval);
     }else{
       this.progressInterval=setTimeout(this.showProgress,1000);
     }
   }
}
```

here id is the id of the progress bar. i used oop since the function showProgress will be called multiple times at same or different time. problem here is that only first time when the function is called am getting the value of this.width as 20 and this.id ="someID" but later i get it as null. Please correct me if am wrong somewhere.

Comment: How are you calling this?

Comment: var progress;
progress=new Progressbar(result);      progress.showProgress();

Answer (score 0):

```
 function Progressbar(id){
  var that=this;
  this.id=id;
  this.width=0;
  this.progressInterval=0;
  this.showProgress=function(){
     that.width+=20;
     document.getElementById(that.id).style.width=that.width + 'px';
     document.getElementById(that.id).innerHTML=that.width + '%';
     if(that.width==100){
        clearTimeout(that.progressInterval);
     }else{
     that.progressInterval=setTimeout(that.showProgress,1000);
   }
 }
```

}

Saving the reference of **this** in a variable worked